# Can I count on all output files being in the bin directory, at the point where a postcompile executes?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

I am having an issue at the moment with a c# project.  I am using Visual Studio 2015 and can reproduce this with a simple console application.

In my project.json file, I have added a simple postcompile script, which copies the contents of the bin directory elsewhere.

The problem I am having, is that often, the first time I do the build, only a few files get copied to the destination directory.
When a second build is done, the rest of the files then get copied over.

It would seem that, the required files are not always in the right place when the postcompile script gets executed.

Is this a bug, or am I incorrectly using this feature?

Comment: What is the "nature" of the files that are initially missing? Are they compiler outputs or e.g. files marked as content?

Comment: Hi and thanks for the comment.  The files that are missing are compiler outputs, such as the dlls from referenced projects in the same solution.